# How do I make my variable have a default value "0" when no input has been provided by the user in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code. I want my variable "a" to hold a default value 0 whenever the user has not given any particular value. I have given my code below:

```
 from tkinter import *
    from tkinter  import messagebox

    def sample(): 
        a= show_values1()
        v= int(a)+10
        print (v)

    def show_values1(event=None):
        global a
        a= i1.get()
        print(a)
        if int(a) > ul or int(a) < ll :
            print('Limit Exceed')
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter values from -100 to 100")

        else :

           return a

    root= Tk()
    ul= 100
    ll=-100
    i1 = inputBox = Entry()
    i1.place(x=70, y=48, height=20)
    bu1=Button(text='Enter', command = show_values1)
    bu1.place(x = 70, y = 28, width=40, height=20)


    bu2=Button(text='SEND', command = sample)
    bu2.bind('<Return>', lambda x: show_values1(event=None))
    bu2.place(x = 70, y = 98, width=40, height=20)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `if not i1.get(): a = "0"`

Comment: You seem to be familiar with `if`/`else` statements - what's holding you back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As li.get() returns a string. Nothing entered will be a string of zero length. You can test for that and then set a to zero. For axample, after your a = i1.get() statement, insert:

```
    if len(a) == 0:
        a = "0"
```

Maybe you also need to handle cases where get() returns values that are not able to be cast to type int. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If no value has been entered, `i1.get()` will have a value of empty string `""`, so you could just test for that inside `showvalues1`:

```
if a == "":
    return 0
```